# Why cant I declare a Intent this way in this context?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class SlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Intent hauptmenu;

hauptmenu = new Intent (this, com.stw.myapplication.Hauptmenu.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intent constructor you are using requires a context for the first parameter.  But since you are in a class that extends PagerAdapter, the "this" keyword does not refer to a context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't declare an `Intent` in that way, but that you can't declare anything that way.

In Java, you can declare an instance in this way:

```
private Intent hauptmenu; //Needs to be initialized later
```

or

```
//Declares and initializes
private Intent hauptmenu = new Intent(this, com.stw.myapplication.Hauptmenu.class);
```

This is the normal approach you're familiar with.

However, you can't declare and initialize in the way you want:

```
private Intent hauptmenu;
hauptmenu = new Intent (this, com.stw.myapplication.Hauptmenu.class);
```

This is because `hauptmenu = new Intent (this, com.stw.myapplication.Hauptmenu.class);` is a **Statement** and normal statements can't run outside of a Statement Block, such as a Method Block.

A Block is indicated by braces { }.

So if you want to initialize an object outside of a Constructor or Methods, you must place the code inside of a Block known as an Initializer Block, like so:

```
private Intent hauptmenu;
{
    hauptmenu = new Intent(this, com.stw.myapplication.Hauptmenu.class);
    Log.i(TAG, "Created an Intent");
}
```

With Initializer Blocks, you can even run other types of code *(shown by my example of logging my creation of an Intent)*. This is something that you can't do when initializing variables during declaration, *outside of purposely creating a method to do so*.

So to answer your question, you can't declare an `Intent` in the way you wanted to, because Java doesn't allow statements, *other than a Declaration Statement*, outside of a Block.

So if you want to create your Intent in the way you want, you simply have to add the braces around your statement. This will cause your initializing statement to be inside of an Initializer Block, thereby making it possible to run.